# JavaScript or jQuery to convert css files according to screen size

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, responsive-design

I can target all browsers using this code:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" media="screen and (min-device-width: 1024px)" href="large.css"/> 
<link rel='stylesheet' media='screen and (min-width: 1023px) and (max-width: 1025px)' href='medium.css' />
<link rel='stylesheet' media="screen and (min-width: 419px) and (max-width: 1023px)"  href='small.css' />
```

But media query design does not work on old versions of IE, so I have a problem with that browser as usual.

Comment: This is not a question. If you need research, please do it yourself, that is not what stackoverflow is about.

Comment: it must be one html file with several css for different screen sizes

Comment: `but media query design does not work on old versions of IE `. Could you elaborate on this? Any error messages? What version of IE are you running it on and have you used any broswer debug tools on it to check if there is any client script errors? Any information defining `does not work` helps.

Comment: And I need someone to clean my house. But we both will live with the disappointment. Show us some effort, this is not give me the script/code kind of a place!

Comment: @François Wahl — Umm. IE8 and lower just don't support media queries. What elaboration is needed? Why would there be an error message?

Comment: "JavaScript or jQuery" makes no sense though. jQuery is just a JavaScript library.

Comment: @Quentin, Umm. Didn't know myself about that. That is why I was asking. Saying `does not work` is not really defining the issue. It helps to state if any errors are encountered or even state if they are none. Your comment might be better as an answer though as that might be the reason it is not working?

Comment: @François Wahl — The question appears to be "IE 8 and lower don't support media queries; what JavaScript can I use instead?" so my comment doesn't suffice as an answer.

Answer (score 1):

Use this jQuery snipet to set a class on the BODY tag:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  var width = $(window).width();
  var class = 'small';

  if(width > 1024) {
    class = 'large';
  } else if(width > 1023 && width < 1025) {
    class = 'medium';
  }

  $('body').addClass(class);
});
```

With appropriate class (large/medium/small) on your BODY you are able to write CSS like this:

```
 body.large p {font-size: 25px};
 body.medium p {font-size: 20px};
 body.small p {font-size: 15px};
```

etc.

Comment: the script doesnt work ,what should i write in body tag and am i need to add jquery link in head

Comment: Yes, it uses jQuery so you need to load jQuery in the HEAD section.

Comment: what about calling function in body?

Comment: can you write to me the jquery link pls

Comment: Hm, sure. <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>

Comment: what about calling function in body

Comment: I'm not sure what you are asking for. Use the script I've provided inside SCRIPT tags in the HEAD section below the jQuery SCRIPT and it should work.

Comment: thank you for your help but it doesn`t work

Answer (score 1):

There are a number of [polyfills listed on the moderizer wiki](https://github.com/Modernizr/Modernizr/wiki/HTML5-Cross-Browser-Polyfills) that includes several claiming to support media queries.

Answer (score 0):

I really recommend using a javascript alternative like syze for example.

http://rezitech.github.com/syze/